# Ways to use unicode fonts (non-english) in android system using keyboard app or a service

Tags: android, unicode, service, fonts, keyboard

I created a keyboard app that will use unicode for keys characters and input. The language is not available on the current android system fonts available. So I loaded it in my app and assigned it on a TextView in the MainActivity.

I can see the characters in the app's TextView when I type using the keyboard. But when I change to some other application like a Message App, it doesn't show. (I am currently not loading the characters on the keyboard keys because that is a separate thing)

So I googled and find nothing to fix this problem. (I don't want rooting). I was thinking of this,

Can I load the font to some kind of a service so that all apps can use the font? OR is there any way to work around on this? I am open to any suggestion. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If the device does not support `UTF-8` fonts/characters, There is no workaround to achieve such functionality. However, you can create a custom keyboard for it but it will be limited to your application only. finally the answer is there is no way to achieve it if the device does not support utf-8 encoding.